# VoiceOver stops announcing UIAccessibilityPostNotification messages

Tags: ios, voiceover, uiaccessibility-notification

I'm working on an application that is designed to speak some information about the data it captures from video as the video is being captured. Right now I'm using `UIAccessibilityPostNotification` to get VoiceOver to say what I want it to say with `UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification`. This typically works great until the user attempts to navigate between my UI controls. After swiping back and forth along the elements (a menu and an info button) a little bit, the application stops speaking the persistent notifications. I also find that posted notifications do not announce if I background the app and then return it to the foreground

I have a magic tap handler that pauses and resumes that persistent announcement and once it is triggered (which also triggers speech about the last rendered info), manually triggered speech works again and upon resume from a second magic tap the announcements continue as if nothing had stopped.

Is there a mechanism to get voiceover to reliably resume speaking without requiring some other kind of user-screen input in between?

Comment: That behavior is unexpected and sounds like a bug. Have you considered filing a Radar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately this was, following the rule of "it's probably your own code's fault first", my own fault. A timer was inadvertently changing the state of things and what I was using to track when to announce was being set to an invalid state which stopped the announcements.